# I don't understand this vector declaration statement

Tags: c++, vector

Why `LOG` and `0` are used in this statement? 
    `LOG = 35;
 vector<int> cnt(LOG, 0); //here cnt is a vector name`

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I assume this is supposed to be C++? Please tag the programming language/framework/tool you are using. Also please provide context for your question, a [repro] preferably. How is `LOG` declared, what confuses you about the statement?

Comment: Check all the constructor variants of `vector`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is constructing a `std::vector`, so you should look at [help documentation for the `vector` constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).

In this case, `LOG` and `0` are being used specifically in the **two-parameter** override of the constructor.

1. `LOG` is used to specify the initial size of the vector;
2. `0` is used to specify the initial value of the elements.

In other words, the expression declares a vector named `cnt` being of size 35 with all elements initialized to 0.